# Command Line to call Batch File within a batch file in the correct directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file in `c:\test.bat`. The command in this batch file is:

```
C:
CALL test.bat
```

Inside my test.bat I have:

```
\Tables\batch.bat
```

The command line calls `test.bat` just fine, but when it gets to the the command `\Tables\batch.bat` it says:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

If I change `test.bat` to the following it works just fine:

```
CD Tables
CALL batch.bat
```

But I can't change `test.dat` for other reasons. Is there a way to call the `test.bat` and make sure that my directory is the `Tables` directory? `Test.dat` has more than one command, so there is another one for `\Sprocs\test2.bat`

Comment: It appears that you are assuming that the current directory is the root directory. Try removing the \ before `Tables`. As a test, add `ECHO %CD%`  as the first line of `test.bat`.

Comment: @Liturgist Thanks for the response. By removing the "\" it makes it better. Although the next batch file fails the command:C:\>sqlcmd -dXXX -UXX -Pxxxxxx -Sxxxxxxxx -it_table.sql -r1
Sqlcmd: 't_table.sql': Invalid filename.

Comment: Why do you have a ">" in the command `C:\>sqlcmd -dXXX -UXX -Pxxx...`?

Comment: Sorry, that was just the copy and paste from command prompt. `C:\>` is the path the command in running from.

Answer (score 0):

`\Tables\batch.bat` means file `batch.bat` is in a subdirectory `Tables` in **root of current drive**.

`.\Tables\batch.bat` or just `Tables\batch.bat` means file `batch.bat` is in a subdirectory `Tables` of **current directory**.

`..\Tables\batch.bat` means file `batch.bat` is in a subdirectory `Tables` of **parent directory of current directory**. In other words `Tables` is a directory parallel to current directory.

Therefore follow the advice of [Liturgist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447901/liturgist) and remove first `\` to reference the file `batch.bat` in subdirectory `Tables` in **current directory**.

By the way:

`C:` switches the current drive to drive `C:`. But this does not define which directory is the current directory on drive `C:`. Use the following command to make a specific directory the current directory on drive `C:` independent on what is currently the current drive and current directory.

```
cd /D "C:\Path\To\Directory"
```

In case of batch file is also running and the directory containing the batch file should become the current directory use:

```
cd /D "%~dp0"
```

or

```
pushd "%~dp0"
```

For details on those two commands, open a command prompt window and run from within the window `cd /?` and `pushd /?` to get help for those two commands displayed. `call /?` explains `%~dp0` (drive and path of argument 0 - the batch file).

Comment: Thanks for the response. By removing the "\" it makes it better. Although the next batch file fails the command:C:\>sqlcmd -dXXX -UXX -Pxxxxxx -Sxxxxxxxx -it_table.sql -r1
Sqlcmd: 't_table.sql': Invalid filename.  FYI: the t_table.sql is under Tables subdirectory.

Comment: Well, if `batch.bat` in `Tables` expects that directory `Tables` is the current directory, your `batch.bat` should contain at top `pushd "%~dp0"` and at bottom `popd`. Or you run `sqlcmd` with specifying fully qualified file names for all files, i.e. use something like `"Path to SqlCmd\sqlcmd.exe" -dXXX -UXX -Pxxxxxx -Sxxxxxxxx -i "%~dp0t_table.sql" -r1`.

Comment: Adding the "at top pushd "%~dp0" and at bottom popd" still gives me the invalid filename. It looks like the system is looking for a file in C: but running it in the Tables directory.

Comment: So you have added `pushd "%~dp0"` at top and `popd` at bottom of `test.bat` and use in `test.bat` now `call Tables\batch.bat`. Is that right? Does `batch.bat` expect that current directory is the directory of this batch file because you reference file and folders without complete path? Yes, then you would need in this batch file also `pushd "%~dp0"` and `popd` as otherwise the current directory is the parent directory of `batch.bat` containing `test.bat`. By the way: `echo %CD%` put into your batch files lets you see (usually) what is the current directory on executing this line on processing.